# Raspian uninstall startx

Tags: raspberry-pi, openbox

I have installed, on my rpi , the Operating System Raspian and when i try raspi-config boot throught the autologin-desktop start LXDE.
I would like starting the desktop of OPENBOX and uninstall the desktop of raspian.
How can be done?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the feeling you don't fully understand the difference between services like Openbox and Xorg.

Openbox is a window manager (much like LXDE, which is built on top of Openbox itself), so you can just apt-get install it. Whereas `startx` is a command from the Xorg package.

If you want to use Openbox instead of LXDE, you need to edit your `.xinitrc` file, located in your user folder, or edit the global `xinitrc` file, located at `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

You'll need to replace `exec startlxde` with `exec openbox-session`.

Comment: In that script , there wasn't exec starlxde but one string : Xdesession... I replace that with : "exec openbox-session" and i resolve my problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I suppose `exec startlxde` also runs `xdesession`. Glad I could resolve your problem. :)

Comment: Do you know where i can find a deep  information of all raspberry boot process ?